# Scroll calls ajax at wrong time

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to use the following function to load an ajax call when the user scrolls to the bottom. However, for some reason the function only fires the ajax call when the user scrolls to down and then back to the top.  Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{   
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{
    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
    $.ajax({
    url: "loadmore.php",
    success: function(html)
    {
        if(html)
        {
            var el = jQuery(html);
            jQuery(".content").append(el).masonry( 'appended', el, true );
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
        }else
        {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
        }
    }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: What's arguments of `scrollTop` in your code are supposed to do?

Comment: Instead of reading the scroll offset using scrollTop, you actually set a new value? Try $(window).scrollTop() instead

Comment: Sorry I had an error earlier. I originally meant to put $(window).scrollTop() and that is when the error occurs. I updated my code to be the code I was using. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it like this:

```
  fetchContent = function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        console.log('At bottom!!');

        // Remove the handler temporarily, so no more scroll events will fire.
        $(window).off('scroll', fetchContent);

        // Make the AJAX call.
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
              url: "loadmore.php",
              success: function(html)
              {
                 if(html)
                 {
                     var el = jQuery(html);
                     jQuery(".content").append(el).masonry( 'appended', el, true );
                     $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                 }else
                 {
                     $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                 }
                 // Re-attach the handler, so scroll events will fire again
                 $(window).on('scroll', fetchContent);
              }
             });
     }
  };

  $(function() {
      $(window).on('scroll', fetchContent);
  });
```

EDIT:

I've done a JSBin which displays a div when user scrolls to the bottom. You can see it here: http://jsbin.com/axobow/2

I know that's not exactly what you need, but it should give you an idea. Iv'e also updated the code a little bit to go inline with what you should have as the final product.

Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! However, when using this code and I scroll about 1/3rd of the way down the screen, it fires off the ajax call multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)  {
           //do your stuff here

        }


    });
```